# Print only specific parts of json file

Tags: python, json, api

I am wondering what I am doing wrong when trying to print the data of name of the following code in python.

```
        import urllib.request, json 
    with urllib.request.urlopen("<THIS IS A URL IN THE ORIGINAL SCRIPT>") as url:
        data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    print (data['Departure']['Product']['name'])
print (data['Departure']['Stops']['Stop'][0]['depTime'])
```

And this is the api I am fetching the data from:

```
    {
  "Departure" : [ {
    "Product" : {
      "name" : "Länstrafik - Buss 201",
      "num" : "201",
      "catCode" : "7",
      "catOutS" : "BLT",
      "catOutL" : "Länstrafik - Buss",
      "operatorCode" : "254",
      "operator" : "JLT",
      "operatorUrl" : "http://www.jlt.se"
    },
    "Stops" : {
      "Stop" : [ {
        "name" : "Gislaved Lundåkerskolan",
        "id" : "740040260",
        "extId" : "740040260",
        "routeIdx" : 12,
        "lon" : 13.530096,
        "lat" : 57.298178,
        "depTime" : "20:55:00",
        "depDate" : "2019-03-05"
      }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please indent your python code properly so the people can better understand your code and be more eagle to help you.

Answer (score 0):

`data["Departure"]` is a list, and you are indexing into it like it's a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote the dictionary sample confusingly. Here's how I think it looks:

```
d =     {
  "Departure" : [ {
    "Product" : {
      "name" : "Länstrafik - Buss 201",
      "num" : "201",
      "catCode" : "7",
      "catOutS" : "BLT",
      "catOutL" : "Länstrafik - Buss",
      "operatorCode" : "254",
      "operator" : "JLT",
      "operatorUrl" : "http://www.jlt.se"
    },
    "Stops" : {
      "Stop" : [ {
        "name" : "Gislaved Lundåkerskolan",
        "id" : "740040260",
        "extId" : "740040260",
        "routeIdx" : 12,
        "lon" : 13.530096,
        "lat" : 57.298178,
        "depTime" : "20:55:00",
        "depDate" : "2019-03-05"
      }]}}]}
```

And here's how you can print `depTime`

```
print(d["Departure"][0]["Stops"]["Stop"][0]["depTime"])
```

The important part you missed is `d["Departure"][0]` because `d["Departure"]` is a `list`.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Albin/Pythontest.py", line 4, in <module>
    print (data['Departure']['Product']['name'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: I still get this error code, what might be the problem?

Comment: @AlbinKarlsson that error code indicates you didn't actually make the change I suggested. It says `data['Departure']['Product']['name']` instead of `data["Departure"][0]["Stops"]["Stop"][0]["depTime"]`

Comment: Okay, I see! Thanks alot for the help! Since i see that you know what you are talking about. what would I have to do if there is another Product in the json file that I would also like to print, for example Product 
name "Länstrafik - Buss 243" further down in the json file, is there any way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like a for-loop, as in `for product_name in data["Product"]:`

Comment: Huh? I am pretty new to this so I am not sure what you meant by that. What should I replace product_name with and what should I replace Product with?

Answer (score 0):

As Kyle said in the previous answer, `data["Departure"]` is a list, but you're trying to use it as a dictionary. There are 2 possible solutions.

1. Change `data["Departure"]["Stops"]["Stop"]` etc. to `data["Departure"][0]["Stops"]["Stop"]` etc.
2. Change the JSON file to make departure into a dictionary, which would allow you to keep your original code. This would make the final JSON snippet look like this:

```
"Departure" : {
  "Product" : {
    "name" : "Länstrafik - Buss 201",
    "num" : "201",
    "catCode" : "7",
    "catOutS" : "BLT",
    "catOutL" : "Länstrafik - Buss",
    "operatorCode" : "254",
    "operator" : "JLT",
    "operatorUrl" : "http://www.jlt.se"
  },
  "Stops" : {
    "name" : "Gislaved Lundåkerskolan",
    "id" : "740040260",
    "extId" : "740040260",
    "routeIdx" : 12,
    "lon" : 13.530096,
    "lat" : 57.298178,
    "depTime" : "20:55:00",
    "depDate" : "2019-03-05"
  }
}
```

Comment: I am still getting this error code: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Albin/Pythontest.py", line 4, in <module>
    print (data['Departure']['Product']['name'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Hmm, ok. Could you maybe tell me what it says when you print the data? As in `print(data)`